# Cockpit -- how to add user options to start VM with QEMU/KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, cockpit

I used Cockipt (host is the CentOS8) to create a guest VM (CentOS8 also). Now I have a task to configure the VM to use stuff from SPDK's VHOST. According SPDK docs I'm need to add follow lines to QEMU's command line :

```
**-chardev socket,id=char0,path=/var/tmp/vhost.0
-device vhost-user-scsi-pci,id=scsi0,chardev=char0**
```

So, the question is : how to add "user" options ? I did not found anything in the Cockpit's  web interface, so is there what I can do manually ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it from cockpit but you can [edit qemu command line options](https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#pass-through-of-arbitrary-qemu-commands) into the virtual machine XML configuration yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into.